# im facing a problem while installing npm install mangoose

Tags: npm

```
PS C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Complete Web Development Bootcamp\mongoosejs> npm install mongoose
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org  
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-08T04_52_02_331Z-debug-0.log
```

i try

```
npm install mongoose
npm cache clean
npm install -s mongoose
npm install -g mongoose
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a proxy problem the "-d flag" solved the issue in my case:

```
npm install -d mongoose
```